# redirect List<Data> to a view after user has submitting a form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form where the user enter his/her details.

```
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Coupons"))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="page-header">Generer Coupon</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Student)
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Student, new SelectList(Model.Students, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control input-lg" })

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Price)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new { @class = "form-control input-lg" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.NumberOfCoupons)
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberOfCoupons, new {@class = "form-control input-lg"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Generer</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
```

I redirect the view to the Create Method on CouponsController

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CouponViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var model = new CouponViewModel
            {
                Students = _context.Students.ToList()
            };
            return View("Index", model);
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= viewModel.NumberOfCoupons; i++)
        {
            var coupon = new Coupon
            {
                CouponNumber = viewModel.CouponNumber,
                ValidationCode = viewModel.ValidationCode(6),
                Price = viewModel.Price,
                StudentId = viewModel.Student,
                DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MMM-dd ddd"))
            };

            _context.Coupons.Add(coupon);

            _context.SaveChanges();

        }

        var coupons = _context.Coupons
           .Where(c => c.StudentId == viewModel.Student)
           .Include(s => s.Student)
           .ToList();

        TempData["viewModel"] = coupons;
        return RedirectToAction("GetCoupons");
    }
```

here is the view i receive the tempdata to display on the view

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCoupons()
    {
        Coupon coupon = TempData["viewModel"] as Coupon;

        return View("Print", (IEnumerable<Coupon>)coupon);
    }
```

I have been stucked for like 3 days. I don't know where im wrong

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? `GetCoupons()` should be `[HttpGet]` and you might consider passing just the id and doing the lookup in the redirected action. You could avoid the `TempData` that way. You are also casting a collection to a single `Coupon`.

Comment: "You are also casting a collection to a single Coupon"... I tried not to cast but i don't know how to do that.
How to pass the id.?

Comment: When i run the project, it says "The resource /Coupons/Getcoupons can't be find"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your example. But you can eliminate them if you do some things differently.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CouponViewModel viewModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("GetCoupons", new { studentId = viewModel.Student });
}
```

First, your redirected action needs to be marked `[HttpGet]`. You can also avoid `TempData` if you pass the id on the query string, then perform the lookup in the redirected action.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCoupons(int studentId)
{
    var coupons = _context.Coupons
       .Where(c => c.StudentId == studentId)
       .Include(s => s.Student)
       .ToList();

    return View("Print", coupons);
}
```

`TempData` isn't wrong but it won't persist on a refresh. Sometimes you will pass sensitive data which makes it useful then. Your cast to a single `Coupon` isn't quite what you want -- Cast to a collection instead.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCoupons()
{
    var coupons = TempData["viewModel"] as IEnumerable<Coupon>;
    return View("Print", coupons);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jasen. I made the changes and it works perfectly